# How Mysql indexes works in case of JOIN?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Suppose I have two tables `patient`, `person`
Mysql query is like below.

```
select fname , lname 
from patient p 
left join per on (per.person_id=p.person_id) 
where p.account_id=2 and (per.fname like  'will%'  OR per.lname like 'will%' ).
```

In case of this query how mysql will use index created on  `(p.account_id,p.person_id)`

`person_id` is a foreign key from `person` table in `patient` table. .

Comment: share the table structure - use show create table patient; show create table person;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you do not want `LEFT`.  With `LEFT JOIN`, you are asking for account #2 whether or not he is named 'will'.

```
SELECT fname, lname
    FROM patient p
    JOIN per ON per.person_id = p.person_id
    WHERE p.account_id = 2
      AND (per.fname LIKE 'will% OR per.lname LIKE 'will%')
```

will find the full name of account #2 if it is a 'will', else return nothing.

You have not said what indexes you have, so we cannot explain your existing indexes.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

For either version of the query, these indexes are the only useful ones:

```
p:  INDEX(account_id)  -- if it is not already the PRIMARY KEY
per:  INDEX(person_id)  -- again, if it is not already the PRIMARY KEY.
```

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` index.

The first index (or PK) would be a quick lookup to find the row(s) with `account_id=2`.  The second would make the join work well.  No index is useful for "will" because of the `OR`.

The query will look at `patient` first, then `per`, using "Nested Loop Join".

Please also provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, so we can discuss the things I am guessing about.